# "Ужасно красивый"

Tags: этимология, лексика

Вдруг задумалась: а почему в русском языке слова "ужасно", "страшно", оборот "до жути" могут употребляться и в значении "очень"? И отсюда появляются "ужасно красивые" и "до жути обаятельные".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то вопрос "Почему?" в таких случаях обычно не задают. Так уж сложилось.
Да это и не только в русском. В английском, например, terrible в некоторых контекстах может означать крайнюю степень чего-либо.
Ну а "логика" тут понятна. Степень, скажем, красоты поражает как ужас или страх.
Кстати, само слово "поражает" - из того же "переносного" ряда. Разить, поражать - бить оружием, наносисть ущерб здоровью. Разве красота может "бить"?

Answer (score 0):

Степень красоты, правда, может настолько поражать, что сопрягается с коннотациями ужаса, страха. Но все это, разумеется, в переносном значении. К тому же подобное использование оборота "страшно красив" наблюдается уже у Антона Павловича Чехова в рассказе "Красавицы", так что тут еще и литературный фактор играет свою роль: "...все глядят на закат и все до одного находят, что он страшно красив, но никто не знает и не скажет, в чем тут красота".

Answer (score 0):

Красивый не может быть "ужасно". Это два взаимоисключающих слова. Может быть очень красивый, ослепительно красив. Или просто красивый.

Comment: Ирина, очень даже может быть. Удивительно, что вы никогда не слышала подобного сочетания.

Comment: Так говорят только невежды. Например, такие, которые пишут:"вы никогда не слышала".

Comment: @Ирина Цветкова, Вы ведете себя неприлично. Выражение "ужасно красивый" можно рассматривать как парадоксальный оборот, усиливающий смысл. А вот на личности переходить не надо!

Answer (score 0):

Это стилистический прием - оксиморон (или оксюморон, и так и так верно), филологи это знают. Этот оборот используется во всех языках. О невежестве или безграмотности здесь речь не идет, это такой же стилистический прием как и эпитеты, каламбуры и прочие.